# Array In mysql procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-administration

I have an issue related to array in mysql procedure? I want to use array as datatype in mysql procedure . I have to store some data into array and later on use that as per requirement. But I really don't know how to use or define or declare array in mysql. I read some where that mysql doesn't support arrays.

Is there any alternative in mysql to array which is not array but works as an array?

Comment: There is no array data type in MySQL.

Comment: What is the practical use of array in procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary table (perhaps a memory temp table) to store your array values. Then you can use that table in JOINs, etc.

Example:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS test;     -- make sure it doesnt already exist
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (
  id int unsigned,
  primary key(id) -- do we want to enforce array as a set?
) ENGINE=memory;

-- use it
...

-- drop it
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE test;
```